# the meaning of stomachache in this sentence

Tags: word-meaning

Please tell me the meaning of stomachache in this sentence:

I usually go away with a stomachache because I think there is a lot of disregard for the way people are treated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The word "stomachache" in this context is used figuratively to convey the idea that he feels disgusted (i.e. sick to his stomach), presumably by his observation that people are treated poorly.